# Cannot install opendkim because cannot find bsd/string.h

Tags: linux, email, installation, dkim

I tried to install [OpenDKIM 2.9.2](http://www.opendkim.org/INSTALL) on AWS to generate the DKIM public & private keys. And when I run `sudo ./configure --with-openssl=/usr/include/openssl` under the opendkim source code folder, it gave me the following error messages.

```
checking bsd/string.h usability... no
checking bsd/string.h presence... no
checking for bsd/string.h... no
checking for strlcat... no
checking for library containing strlcat... no
checking for library containing strlcpy... no
checking for strlcpy... no
checking for library containing strlcat... (cached) no
checking for library containing strlcpy... (cached) no
configure: error: no strlcpy/strlcat found
```

I searched the system and I found the string.h files locate at the following folders

```
/usr/include/bits/string.h
/usr/include/string.h
/usr/include/linux/string.h
```

And I created a folder called `bsd` under `/usr/include` (`/usr/include/bsd`), and created a soft link to the `/usr/include/string.h`. Then the install process can find the `string.h` file, but it still cannot find the `strlcat` and `strlcpy` functions in that file. So I guess that I need to installed `libbsd`. Then I ran "`whereis libbsd`" and I got "`/usr/lib64/libbsd.a`". So I guess that the lib has been installed.

So now I have no idea about how to fix the issue and install OpenDKIM from source.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to install **libbsd-dev**

if you are using ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get install  libbsd-dev
```

if you are using centOS

```
sudo yum install  libbsd-devel
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: Maybe AWS EC2 server is not using the redhat yum repo list. When I ran  `yum info libbsd-dev`, YUM cannot find a match. Is there a way that I can manually install that lib?

Comment: I found source code for libbsd-dev and I installed it. Then I install the opendkim again, and now the install process can find the string.h file, but it still cannot find the functions. I guess that the `.h` file only defines the function name and because AWS EC2 use redhat OS and it is not a bsd OS, there are no implementations of those functions. Am i right? And if I cannot fix this, is there a opendkim package for redhat? (Linux version 3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64 (mockbuild@gobi-build-31002) (gcc version 4.8.2 20131212 (Red Hat 4.8.2-7) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Wed Apr 2 09:36:59 UTC 2014)

Comment: it seems like compiler don't able to find libbsd please reinstall it

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. And I checked the content of the string.h file from libbsd-dev, and it didn't contain function body. I will try to create a local repo and let yum to search the dependancies. Maybe I don't have the dependancies installed.

Comment: I have figured out how to do it. Because I just need to generate the key, I didn't check other stuff but "opendkim-genkey" command. First, I installed "libbsd-0.6.0-3.fc21.x86_64.rpm" and "libbsd-devel-0.6.0-3.fc21.x86_64.rpm" on AWS EC2, and then installed "sendmail-devel". At last, get "opendkim-2.9.2.tar.gz" and install it like other linux package. Then the "opendkim-genkey" command has been installed and it is working.

Comment: I am agree with @Pavel, just try`sudo yum install  libbsd-devel`

Answer (score 2):

I realize an answer has already been selected. But this worked for me on a new CentOS 6.x installation on DigitalOcean.

1. Install RHEL EPEL Repos

   `wget http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
   wget http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/remi-release-6.rpm
   sudo rpm -Uvh remi-release-6*.rpm epel-release-6*.rpm`
2. Yum for libbsd-devel

   `yum install libbsd-devel`

Reference:
[Installing RHEL EPEL Repo on Centos 5.x or 6.x](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/installing-rhel-epel-repo-on-centos-5x-or-6x),
[pkgs.org](http://pkgs.org/centos-6/epel-x86_64/libbsd-devel-0.6.0-1.el6.x86_64.rpm.html)

Answer (score 0):

Also a note even though this has been closed - Amazon EC2 Linux also needs the EPEL repos...

```
yum-config-manager --enable epel > /dev/null
yum update
yum install libbsd-devel
```